# Ubuntu 20.04 fix for chrome screen tearing

Tags: display, screen, window-manager, tearing

When starting chrome without window manager I notice screen tearing when watching YouTube.

This doesn't happen when I'm in Ubuntu desktop so I'm trying to track down whatever fix Ubuntu desktop applies and see if I can use that without a window manager.

Im using an Intel gpu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are having the same issue that I was having but disabling "hardware acceleration" in google settings solved it for me